# When to call dispose and clear on CompositeDisposable

Tags: android, rx-java2

My question can be a duplicate of [How to use CompositeDisposable of RxJava 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203791/how-to-use-compositedisposable-of-rxjava-2) But asking to clear one more doubt. 
According to the accepted answer

```
// Using clear will clear all, but can accept new disposable
disposables.clear(); 
// Using dispose will clear all and set isDisposed = true, so it will not accept any new disposable
disposables.dispose();
```

In my case, I'm using fragments as my views (View layer in MVP) and in some scenarios, I add active fragment to backstack, which actually does not kill the Fragment but only its view. Which means only `onDestroyView` is called and not the `onDestroy` . And later I can come back to the same fragment which is in the backstack, so only its view is being re-created.
I have a `CompositeDisposable` as the member of my `BaseFragment` which holds subscriptions.

My question is, should I call `clear` on `CompositeDisposable` each time on `onDestroyView`? So that it can again take subscriptions once the view is resumed?  And call `dispose` on the `onDestroy`, so that when the fragment itself is destroyed no need to take disposables anymore?

If it is wrong what is the proper way to handle. When `clear` and `dispose` have to be called.?

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever call dispose over clear. The only difference is it will automatically dispose any future observables added to it. Can't personally think of a usecase for this although I'm sure there are plenty...

Answer (score 25):

You're right, you can save yourself from creating a new `CompositeDisposable` for each time the corresponding view is created, but instead treat a `CompositeDisposable` as a single instance tied to the `onCreate/onDestroy` lifecycle methods and treat aggregated disposables as part of the fragment view calling `clear` in `onDestroyView`.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using Composite`Disposable.dispose()`, you can better use `CompositeDisposable.clear()` so you don't have to create a new CompositeDisposable: [method documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/CompositeDisposable.html).

```
clear() //Atomically clears the container, then disposes all the previously contained Disposables.

dispose() //Dispose the resource, the operation should be idempotent.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();


// adding an Observable to the disposable
disposables.add(sampleObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String value) {
                    }
                }));

    static Observable<String> sampleObservable() {
        return Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<? extends String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<? extends String> call() throws Exception {
                // Do some long running operation
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                return Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
            }
        });
    }                


// Using clear will clear all, but can accept new disposable
disposables.clear(); 
// Using dispose will clear all and set isDisposed = true, so it will not accept any new disposable
disposables.dispose();
```

- Clear - onStop()
- Dispose - onDestroy()

I have created a sample project to demonstrate the use of RxJava2. Here you can find the [sample project - RxJava2-Android-Samples](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples)

Comment: Hello, do you happen to know how I can fix my issue  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req ( it's based off of your library )

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. I fixed it with the following method
BaseAbstractPresenter:

```
  protected lateinit var compositeDisposable : CompositeDisposable

@CallSuper
override fun attachView(view: BaseView) {
    compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
}

@CallSuper
override fun detachView() {
    if(this::compositeDisposable.isInitialized)
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
}
```