# What is the best practice of using CompositeDisposables

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I tried calling it on the onComplete() block but compositeDisposables.clear() with retrofit network calls causes the calls to be cancelled midway.

```
                               observable.......
                               .subscribe(
                                {
                                    utilModule.logI("net repo response")
                                    //cleanDisposables()//this causes HttpOk cancelled error
                                },
                                {
                                    utilModule.logI("no repo response" + it.message)
                                    //cleanDisposables()
                                }
                        ))
    }

    private fun cleanDisposables() {
        //clean old network observables, dispose will prevent further observing
        utilModule.logI("disposing observables")
        if (!compositeDisposables.isDisposed) {
            compositeDisposables.clear()
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057885/when-to-call-dispose-and-clear-on-compositedisposable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically your disposables would be tied to your activity or fragments lifecycle and clear in onDestroy.

This could be an example using MVP design pattern...

```
presenter.kt
fun dispose() {
    compositeDisposable.clear()
}


activity.kt
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    presenter.dispose()
}
```

Comment: My disposables are in the repository class which is referenced in the presenter, that's two layers away from the activity/fragment. This seems to be getting messy.

Comment: Have you tried calling cleanDisposables() in .doOnComplete{ }?

Comment: i m little confused , so to clear a compositedisposable in presenter ( mvp ) , we can Dooncomplete() and inside it , we compositeDisposable.clear(), is that correct

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it in MVVM. I have LifeCycle-ed Activity that subscibes to my ViewModel. Then In ViewModel class I have instance of `CompositeDisposable`. I do `clear` it in the ViewModel `onCleared` method.

here is a stub

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MyRepo mRepo;
    private CompositeDisposable mDisposables = new CompositeDisposable();


    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mRepo = MysRepo.getInstance(...);
    }

    public void loadData()
    {
        Disposable d = mRepo.getMyPeculiarData()
                ...
                .subscribe(...);

        mDisposables.add(d);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        mDisposables.clear();
    }

}
```