# RxJava subscription not working after adding to CompositeDisposable

Tags: rx-java2

I'm using `RxJava Flowable with Room` where I listen to changes in a table. The problem as mentioned is that `when the result of subscribe, a disposable, is added to a CompositeDisposable, it immediately unsubscribes`.

Below is the relevant code :

```
repo.getFlowable(id)
                ?.doOnDispose { Timber.i("Unsubscribed") }
                ?.doOnDispose { Timber.i("Disposed") }
                ?.subscribe({
                    Timber.i("Subscribed")
                }, {
                    Timber.e(it)

                })?.apply {
                    compositeDisposables.add(this)
                }
```

When the apply block is added, "Unsubscribed" and "disposed" are printed immediately `even though "compositeDisposables.dispose()" is not called.`

Without the apply block, it is working as expected.

Is this an expected behaviour? Why does the subscription gets disposed immediately when the Composite Disposable is not disposed yet?

Comment: Can you add `Timeber.i("isDisposed=${compositeDisposables.isDisposed()}")` just before the add line to confirm it is not disposed

Comment: @SanlokLee It is true.

Comment: Check if the `compositeDisposable` was disposed before, because if it was, it will instantly dispose any disposable that is newly added to it

Comment: @AhmedAshrafGamal Yes, this disposable is kept with the intention of disposing multiple times. So every time it is disposed, does it need a new composite disposable instance?

Comment: Thanks @AhmedAshrafGamal. Assigning a new instance to the variable every time it is disposed works. Please let me know if this is not the right way of handling this.

Comment: If you want to dispose multiple times but want to keep the same `CompositeDisposable` instance, use `CompositeDisposable.clear()` instead of `CompositeDisposable.dispose()`

Comment: @SanlokLee Subscriptions get disposed with the clear method as well.

Comment: @AshwinMahajan, using `clear()` should let disposables to be added again. Can you show us the part where you call `clear()` or `dispose()`?

Comment: @ashwinmahajan no you don't need a new composite disposable everytime, like Sanlok Lee said, if it's intended to be disposed multiple times, use clear() instead of dispose(), 
refer to this answer to know the difference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057885/when-to-call-dispose-and-clear-on-compositedisposable
If it's not intended to be cleared multiple times, please show us the code so that we can help

Answer (score 2):

If `disposed()` is called, you won't be able to perform `add()`anymore, as it will discard immediately.

There are two option solve this issue:

1. Instantiate a `new CompositeDisposable()` and start adding dispose objects. Once you are done you call `dispose()`. If you want to add something more, instantiate `CompositeDispose` again.
2. Instantiate a `new CompositeDisposable()` only once, but instead of `dispose()` you use `clear()`. After this command you will be able to keep adding disposables, without the need to a new `CompositeDispose`